# Archiving a huge database(oracle) without impacting processes that inserts records to it

Tags: database, performance, archive

We have an audit database (oracle) that holds monitor information of all activities performed by services (about 100) deployed on application servers. As you may imagine the audit database is really huge because of the volume of requests the services process. And the only write transaction that occurs on this database is services writing audit information in real-time.

As the audit database started growing (more than a million records per day), querying required data (for example `select all errors occurred with service A for requests between start date and end date`) quickly became nearly impossible.

To address this, some "smart kids" decided to device a batch job that will copy data from the database over to another database (say, audit_archives) and delete records so that only 2 days worth of audit data is retained in audit database.

This initially looked neat but whenever the "batch" process runs, the audit process that inserts data to audit database starts to become very slow - and sometimes the "batch" process also fails due to database contention.

What is a better way to design this scenario to perform above mentioned archival in most efficient way so that there is least impact to the audit process and the batch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to look into partitioning your base table.

Create a mirror table (as the target of the "historic" data) and create the same partitioning scheme on that one (most probably on a per-date basis).

Then you can simply exchange the "old" partitions (using `ALTER TABLE the_table EXCHANGE partition`) from one table to the other. Should only take a few seconds to "move" the partition. The actual performance would depend on the indexes defined (local, global).

This technique is usually used to do it the other way round (prepare new data to be fed into a reporting table in a datawarehouse environment) but should work for "archiving" as well.

Comment: Thanks for your response. One catch here is that out of a 24hr weekday, we can't afford to have the audit table to be unavailable.

Comment: @ringbearer: Why do you think the table will be unavailable?

Comment: `ALTER TABLE the_table EXCHANGE partition`'s side effect?

Comment: @ringbearer: no, the table won't be "unavaiable". There might be some problems with locking but you would need to try that out. I'm not sure if that requires a lock on the table or a lock on the partition.

Answer (score 0):

I Easy way.

1. delete old records partially the best with FORALL statement
2. copy data partially the best with FORALL
3. add partitioning based on day of the week

II Queues

1. delete old records partially the best with FORALL statement
2. fill audit_archives with trigger on audit, in trigger use queue to avoid long dml